# Can a sum of trigonometric functions equal a constant for all inputs?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, fourier-series, trigonometric-series

Let $r_1,...,r_n$ and $\phi_1,...\phi_n$ be real numbers. Consider the following sum:

$S=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}r_k\sin(\phi_k+k\alpha)$

Suppose $S$ is constant for all $\alpha \in R$. Does it necessarily follow that $r_1=r_2=...=r_n=0$?

Comment: Have you tried to re-write your sum using the usual trigonometric formula in order to get a finite Fourier sum?

Comment: I actually don't know anything about Fourier series but I included it as a tag because I thought it be might be relevant.